# ruby at_exit exit status

Tags: ruby, exit, status, atexit

Can i determine selves process exit status in at_exit block?

```
at_exit do
  if this_process_status.success?
    print 'Success'
  else
    print 'Failure'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

using idea from [tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman)

```
at_exit do
  if $!.nil? || ($!.is_a?(SystemExit) && $!.success?)
    print 'success'
  else
    code = $!.is_a?(SystemExit) ? $!.status : 1
    print "failure with code #{code}"
  end
end
```

or without Perlisms:

```
require 'English'

at_exit do
  if $ERROR_INFO.nil? || ($ERROR_INFO.is_a?(SystemExit) && $ERROR_INFO.success?)
    print 'success'
  else
    code = $ERROR_INFO.is_a?(SystemExit) ? $ERROR_INFO.status : 1
    print "failure with code #{code}"
  end
end
```

Comment: just my opinion would be to give the "check" to tadman instead of yourself /shrug.

Comment: I think that the fullest answer should be checked. Check is most useful for other users looking for answer and I don't think that anything will change for me and tadman, whatever answer I will check.

Comment: I think using `at_exit` for this is ok for small scripts. For larger apps, you should be using `exit` (or calling your own method to handle exits) at the intended exit points, and handling errors, exceptions, and signals explicitly.

Comment: What is the `($!.is_a?(SystemExit) && $!.success?)`?

Comment: @Nakilon Check if exit is happening due to explicit call to `exit` (or `raise SystemExit`) and exit code is successful (equal to `0`)

Comment: @tig interesting. I wish the SystemExit had .to_i so you could do $!.to_i.zero? instead of it all.

Comment: @Nakilon It has also `status`, so you can `$!.status.zero?` (or even monkey-patch `to_i` alias), but you still need to check if it is a `SystemExit` first.

Answer (score 20):

Although the documentation on this is really thin, $! is set to be the last exception that occurs, and after an exit() call this is a SystemExit exception. Putting those two together you get this:

```
at_exit do
  if ($!.success?)
    print 'Success'
  else
    print 'Failure'
  end
end
```

Comment: That will be the case only if exit will be called.
Surely I can be test if $! is nil or is SystemExit which answers true on success?
But is it possible to get Process::Status object or it is not created for the top process?

Comment: using your idea I got answer and posted but I don't know which answer is better to mark - yours or mine?

Comment: Whatever works for you. Didn't know you could "answer" your own question, but okay.